# Get Excel Chart datasource

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, charts, excel-charts

It is easy to set a datasource for an Excel Chart with Visual Studio, like

```
Chart.SetSourceData(Source:=SomeRange)
```

But how do I GET (retrieve) the datasource (Range) for an already exisiting Chart in an Excel file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that will parse the ranges out of the series. If you have custom series formulas that don't use ranges, it will probably break.

```
Public Function GetSourceData(ByRef cht As Chart) As Range

    Dim srs As Series
    Dim vaArgs As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rReturn As Range

    For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
        vaArgs = Split(Split(srs.Formula, "SERIES(")(1), ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(vaArgs) - 1
            If rReturn Is Nothing Then
                Set rReturn = Range(vaArgs(i))
            Else
                Set rReturn = Union(rReturn, Range(vaArgs(i)))
            End If
        Next i
    Next srs

    Set GetSourceData = rReturn

End Function
```

Use as:

```
?getsourcedata(activechart).Address
$B$2:$C$2,$A$3:$C$14
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its been solved here already:
Excel VBA - Get chart data range
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28391220/6868389

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio code looks like this:

```
Dim g As String
Dim gg() As String
Dim a As Excel.ChartObject

    a = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.chartobjects(1)
    g = a.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).formula
    gg = g.Split(",")

    MsgBox(gg(2))
```