# Change sheet name of the source data in a diagram using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a diagram on a worksheet. The source data is on another sheet.

I would like to redirect the source data reference in the diagram to a worksheet identical to the first worksheet except for the data.

How can I replace the sheetname of the source data reference in the diagram with the name of the other worksheet?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.setsourcedata

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28391220/2727437

Comment: Find + Replace the sheet name?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. I solved it like this with the help from you guys and some googleing. Not the cleanest code but it works. Thanks!!

```
Sub ReplaceSheetName(strNewSheetName As String)
    Dim srs As Series
    Dim strSourceDataSheetName As String
    Dim strTempFormula As String

    strNewSheetName = "'" & strNewSheetName & "'"
    For Each srs In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection
        If InStr(1, srs.Name, "Budget", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Else
            strSourceDataSheetName = GetSheetNameFromChartSourceData(srs.Formula, "(", "!")
            strTempFormula = Replace(srs.Formula, strSourceDataSheetName, strNewSheetName, vbTextCompare)
            srs.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(srs.Formula, srs.Formula, strTempFormula)
        End If
    Next
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Refresh
End Sub

Private Function GetSheetNameFromChartSourceData(strSourceDataFormula As String, strStartDelimiter As String, strEndDelimiter As String) As String
    Dim firstDelPos As Integer
    Dim secondDelPos As Integer
    Dim stringBwDels As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    firstDelPos = InStr(strSourceDataFormula, strStartDelimiter) 'Position of start delimiter

    'If end delimiter is the same as the start delimiter they will be the same, hence no string is extracted.
    If strStartDelimiter = strEndDelimiter Then
        secondDelPos = InStrRev(strSourceDataFormula, strEndDelimiter) 'Position of end delimiter
    Else
        secondDelPos = InStr(strSourceDataFormula, strEndDelimiter) 'Position of end delimiter
    End If

    If firstDelPos = 0 Or secondDelPos = 0 Then
        stringBwDels = strSourceDataFormula
    Else
        stringBwDels = Mid(strSourceDataFormula, firstDelPos + 1, secondDelPos - firstDelPos - 1) 'Extract the string between two delimiters
    End If

    GetSheetNameFromChartSourceData = stringBwDels
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred while extracting substring between the given separators " & """" & strStartDelimiter & """" & " and " & """" & strEndDelimiter & """" & ". Error message: " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice job. I also had the same problem but I solved it in a shorter way, leveraging on ready-made functions to achieve the same thing. Below is my code

```
Sub changeSheetRef()
'This code replaces the sheet name part of all data series in a plot _
 with the current sheet name

newSheetRef = ActiveSheet.Name

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Activate
        For j = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection().Count
            oldDataSource = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Formula
            oldSheetRef = Split(Split(oldDataSource, ",")(2), "'")(1)
            newDataSource = Replace(oldDataSource, oldSheetRef, newSheetRef)
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Formula = newDataSource
        Next
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.Refresh
Next
MsgBox "All chart data series have been updated to match equivalent data on the current worksheet, courtesy of SaeedSoft Inc.", , "SaeedSoft Inc."
End Sub
```